# Where I can find wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.1.jar?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am trying to install `WebSphere Liberty Server` using command line for which I need a jar and every place I reach out to get the reference of jar location redirects me to [Downloads liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/).

Page is showing me multiple runtime but none of them is having **`wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.1.jar`** inside.

Any idea from where I can have the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download page on wasdev.net only contains the most recent version of the code which is 8.5.5.6. I would recommend taking the most recent release which can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/runtimes-8.5.5-wlp-runtime). If you need 8.5.5.1 then you need to go to fix central to download one. I would give you a download link, but it depends on which edition you want to use. Fix central is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).